# KeyError to existing Colums in my panda dataframe after transposing, with dtype='object'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, object, keyerror, dtype

So i have some trouble with trying to make basic arithmetic with columns in pandas. the datatype of my columns after transposing are 'object'. Because of this i get a `KeyError` when trying to add a column to another column.

After transposing I have added the code:

```
dg.columns = dg.columns.astype(str)
```

The dont seem to react to it, anyone knows how to solve this?

my full code:

```
dg = pd.read_csv("file.csv", encoding="latin-1", header = None)

dg = dg.T
dg.columns= dg.iloc[0]
dg = dg.reindex(dg.index.drop(0))
dg.index.name = 'Date'
dg = dg.fillna(0)
dg.drop(dg.columns.difference(['Category','revenue','Result']), 1, inplace=True)
dg.columns = dg.columns.astype(str)

print (dg.columns)

dg['revenue','Result'] = pd.to_numeric(dg['revenue','Result'], errors='coerce')

dg['cost'] = dg['revenue']* - dg['Result']
dg = dg.groupby('Category','revenue','Result','cost').agg(sum).reset_index()
print (dg[:5])
```

Comment: string dtype is shown as object in pandas. you are not getting a typeError but a keyError which means the columns you are referencing do not exist. can you maybe share some of the data of the csv so we can try to debug it?

Comment: Thank you for the response, here is the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OTKhQ9hqqA7tkzNUYplwY0nfYcmga7Q7/view?usp=sharing